# Writing a SQL query for MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005

i have a table of the following structure

```
id name field1 field2 field3
1  aaa   20     30     40
2  aaa   40     50     60
3  bbb   40     50     60
4  aaa   75     55     60
5  bbb   40     50     60
6  bbb   40     50     60
```

The resultset i want is

```
1 aaa (sum of field 1) (product of field 2) (average of field3)
2 bbb (sum of field 1) (product of field 2) (average of field3)
```

I am not able to find out how to do this. I tried

```
select SUM(field1),PROD(field2),AVG(field3) from table GROUP BY name
```

but its not working. Also i need to find out how to do this in sql server 2005  as well.

Comment: By `Prod` you want to multiply all values in the group? Are they all positive numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server you could use

```
SELECT SUM(field1),
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(CASE
                      WHEN field2 = 0 THEN 1
                    END) > 0 THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END * CASE COUNT(CASE WHEN SIGN(field2) = -1 THEN 1 END )%2
               WHEN 0 THEN 1
               ELSE -1
             END * EXP(SUM(LOG(ABS(NULLIF(field2, 0))))),
       AVG(field3)
FROM   T
GROUP  BY name
```

Comment: @Smith i check that and its working fine now will you please describe what you have did for product of field2

Comment: @rahularyansharma: It's simple math: `log(A*B*...Z)=logA+loB+...+logZ`, therefore: `A*B*...*Z=exp(logA+loB+...+logZ)` (search for logarithm identities for more explanations)

Comment: @rahularyansharma [It is based on here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/the-aggregate-function-product/) but extended to handle zero and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select name, SUM(field1),PROD(field2),AVG(field3) from table GROUP BY name
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have PROD()

Comment: Unless you've written a UDF called `PROD`, there is no `PROD()` function available.

Comment: I'm guessing thats what he meant by `PROD()`, if not, you can create your own function for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table product(
id int identity(1,1),
_name varchar(max),
field1 int,
field2 int,
field3 int
)
create table #_name(
id int identity(1,1),
_name varchar(max),
field1 int,
field2 int,
field3 int
)
insert into product values ('aaa',20,30,40)
insert into product values ('aaa',40,50,60)
insert into product values ('bbb',40,50,60)
insert into product values ('aaa',75,55,60)
insert into product values ('bbb',20,30,40)
insert into product values ('bbb',40,50,60)
insert into product values ('ddd',40,50,60)
insert into product values ('ddd',40,50,60)
insert into product values ('ddd',40,50,60)

declare @name varchar(max);
declare @sum int,@prod int, @avg int;
declare @field2 int;
set @prod=1;

select * from product
declare pro_cursor cursor for 
select p._name from (select distinct(_name) from product)p
open pro_cursor
fetch next from pro_cursor into @name
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin 
    declare field_cursor cursor for
    select field2 from product where _name=@name
    open field_cursor
    fetch next from field_cursor into @field2
    while(@@fetch_status=0)
    begin
        set @prod=@prod*@field2;        
    fetch next from field_cursor into @field2
    end
    close field_cursor
    deallocate field_cursor
    set @sum=(select sum(field1) from product where _name=@name);
    set @avg=(select avg(field3) from product where _name=@name);
insert into #_name values (@name,@sum,@prod,@avg)
set @prod=1;
fetch next from pro_cursor into @name
end
select * from #_name
close pro_cursor
deallocate pro_cursor
truncate table #_name
```